# How can I find and connect devices in GKSessionModeServer/GKSessionModeClient model

Tags: ios, bluetooth, gamekit

Using `GKPeerPickerController` I can easily connect two ios device via bluetogether.But it's only in GKSessionModePeer mode.

I use the code to create session in `GKSessionModeServer` mode

```
GKSession *session=[[GKSession alloc] initWithSessionID:nil displayName:nil sessionMode:GKSessionModeServer];
session.delegate = self;
session.available = YES;
// Set data handler.
[session setDataReceiveHandler:self withContext:nil];
```

And this code to create session in `GKSessionModeClient` mode in another device

```
GKSession *session=[[GKSession alloc] initWithSessionID:nil displayName:nil sessionMode:GKSessionModeClient];
session.delegate = self;
session.available = YES;
// Set data handler.
[session setDataReceiveHandler:self withContext:nil];
```

When I set `session.available =YES` ,some `delegate` method should be called . But nothing happened.Why?

How can I find other devices using the api , and connect them together?
Or any other method can transfer data via bluetooth ?

Comment: You might want to try `GKSessionModePeer` instead, and are you sure that both apps have the same bundle ID? They're running different code, which seems a bit odd.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I fix it.When I set session.available = YES , it will look for other session , and the method:

```
- (void)session:(GKSession *)session peer:(NSString *)peerID didChangeState:(GKPeerConnectionState)state
```

will be called.

You must not release the session when it is searching !!!